# Получение пути построения из svg

Tags: python, svg

Надо конвертировать svg в массив координат типа (x,y), в котором будут описываться путь для построения изображения (контуров) из svg

[здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15857818/python-svg-parser) и [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20808614/parsing-svg-file-paths-with-python/35781017) есть частичные решения для этой проблемы (получить набор формул из svg), но они всё ещё не решают задачу, я не знаю как получить путь из этих формул

как интерпретировать, например `m 30.82,18.12 0,2.543 c 0,1.969 -1.691,3.395 -3.617,3.395 l -6.352,0 c -1.582,0 -2.895,1.578 -2.895,3.145 l 0,5.453 c 0,1.551 1.363,2.461 2.895,2.906 1.832,0.531 3.828,0.633 6.02,0 1.457,-0.418 2.895,-1.258 2.895,-2.906 l 0,-2.184 -5.781,0 0,-0.727 8.68,0 c 1.68,0 2.309,-1.164 2.895,-2.902 0.605,-1.793 0.574,-3.52 0,-5.816 -0.418,-1.66 -1.211,-2.902 -2.895,-2.902 M 27.239,31.93 c 0.598,0 1.086,0.484 1.086,1.086 0,0.602 -0.484,1.098 -1.086,1.098 -0.602,0 -1.09,-0.496 -1.09,-1.098 0,-0.602 0.488,-1.086 1.09,-1.086 m 0,0`

да, это кривая Безье, но меня смущает множество пар координат после "c", как это понять?

буду рад любой помощи

Answer (score 1, accepted):

этот код вернет массив с точками, которые распределены с некоторым шагом

```
from svg.path import parse_path
from xml.dom import minidom

def extract_path(name, freq, scale=1, x_offset=0, y_offset=0):
    doc = minidom.parse(name)
    path_strings = [path.getAttribute('d') for path in doc.getElementsByTagName('path')]
    doc.unlink()

    path = []

    for path_string in path_strings:
        items = parse_path(path_string)
        for item in items:
            leng = item.length()
            step = round(leng/freq)
            for time in range(step):
                time/=step
                pos = item.point(time)
                path.append([(pos.real+x_offset)*scale, (pos.imag+y_offset)*scale])

    return path
```